# I had an active linkedin account but when I tried to login today, I get the message that ID doesn't exist

Tags: linkedin

I had an active linkedIn account but when I tried to login today, I get the message that ID doesn't exist.Even my previous contacts don't see my LinkedIn profile now. Please suggest how can I get back my LinkedIn profile

Comment: Try [Reopening Your Account](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a1342239)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.